# Is there a better-than-brute-force algorithm to generate a graph whose relation is string edit distance=1?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, time-complexity, weighted-graphs, string-metrics

I'm interested in creating a graphs whose vertices are strings, and whose edges represent the relation of having an edit distance of 1 under a given string metric.

An obvious approach is to make all $\frac{n^2-n}{2}$ comparisons among the $n$ vertices, giving us $O(n^2)$ time complexity.

Excluding parallelizing the comparisons, is there a better algorithm in terms of time complexity?

I'm interested in string metrics where strings of different length are allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the worst case any such algorithm will work $\Omega(n^2)$ because your graph can have $\Omega(n^2)$ edges.

By the way, are you interested in some particular string metric?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I'm interested in string metrics where strings of different length are allowed. Not a particular metric, however.

Comment: I like where you're going with the worst possible case; it feels intuitively right. Can you formalize into a logical argument so I can feel assured that it is **nessarily** the case?

Comment: Just assume that there are at least two strings $s_1$ and $s_2$ with edit distance equal 1 (under given metric). Then for each $n$ we can construct graph which has half of its nodes equal to $s_1$ and other half of nodes equal to $s_2$. Obviously, such graph has  $\frac{n^2}{4}$ edges.

Comment: On the other hand, for any $n$ you can always construct a graph which contains arbitrary few vertices. So the best case complexity can be more optimistic (depending on particular metric). However, without some a priory knowledge about a metric it's highly unlikely that we can do something better than full pairwise comparison of graph vertices.

Comment: Okay, I find that compelling. Thanks for clariyfing

Comment: It should be "... a graph which contains arbitrary few EDGES." in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use [BK-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree) to speed this up. Inserting $n$ elements into the tree takes $O(n \log n)$ time. After this you can query the tree for all strings whose edit distance is exactly one away from your input. Doing this for all strings again takes $O(n^2)$ complexity, however with a very small constant factor ([this page](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees) mentions only 5-8% of the tree needs to be inspected per query).

Here's a short description of how it works:

#### Data structure

A BK-Tree is either

- Empty
- A node with a root value $r$ and a set of indexed children $c_i$, each a BK-Tree (implemented using hash map, dynamic array, or similar)

A metric (important!) distance function $d(x,y)$ is used for insertion and queries.

#### Inserting string $s$

- If the tree is empty, make it a new node with $s$ as the root value and no children
- If the tree is a node with root $r$ and children $c_i$, let $k=d(r,s)$.

  - If $k=0$, skip insertion as $s$ is already at the root
  - Otherwise recursively insert $s$ into the $k$-th child tree $c_k$.

The last step makes sure that all nodes in $c_i$ have distance $i$ to the root

#### Querying string $s$

- If the tree is empty, return no results
- If the tree is a node with root $r$ and children $c_i$, let $k=d(r,s)$.

  - If $k=1$, add $r$ as a result (**Note**: This step is different from usual BK-Tree queries)
  - In addition, recursively query $s$ from the children $c_{d-1}$, $c_d$ and $c_{d+1}$. Return all results from those queries as well

The last step there is the magic of BK-Trees, as it doesn't need to check the other children due to the distance being metric. Here's a partial proof of why others don't need to be checked:

Let's assume there was some string $x$ which has distance one from our query, so $d(s, x)=1$, but it's in the child tree $c_{k+2}$. We know that $d(r, x)=k+2$ from the insertion procedure. This however (with the triangle inequality for metric spaces) gives

$$
k+2=d(r, x)\leq d(r, s)+d(s,x)=k+1
$$

But this is a contradiction! Similar can be done for all children with $i>k+1$ and $i<k-1$. This means that all strings in other children won't have distance one by construction, so we don't need to even check them, which saves processing time.

Edit: Another explanation: https://signal-to-noise.xyz/post/bk-tree/